# postgresql materialized view refresh history time

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm working on a project which requires me to write a query to create a materialized view in PostgreSQL. My requirement is that How I can get PostgreSQL materialized view refresh history time for specific materialized view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not store the time when an SQL statement like `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` is run.

Any attempt to rely on the file modification time of the underlying data file is in vain, as jobs like autovacuum may modify the file.

The only way to retain such information is to store the times when you run the statement in a table yourself.

An alternative could be to log all DDL statements (`log_statement = 'ddl'`) and retrieve the information from the log file.